# Would it be faster / using less memory to return in each case of if else?

Tags: c, performance, memory

Recently I got a code example (see code #1) in my CS study and I try to elicit if my second version of the code would be faster or using less memory.
Do you have an answer for my question?

```
// Code #1
double f(double b, double x)
{
    double s;
    if (x == 0.0)
        s = 1.0;
    else
        s = sin(x)/x;
    return s + b;
}

// Code #2
double f(double b, double x)
{
    // I thought this would be faster and using less memory due to 
    // not declaring a new double
    if (x == 0.0)
        return 1.0 + b;
    else
        return sin(x)/x + b;
}
```

Thank you guys for your help.

Comment: c++ is not c, please choose only one tag so you can get the answer you need

Comment: Unless the compiler you're using is ****, they'll probably be optimized down to the same code. You could always disassemble and see for yourself. In theory the second would probably be faster, just likely not in practice.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the tags. I thought it would not do any difference if C or C++

Comment: You should ask it in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The only way to be sure is to perform tests yourself. Though any good optimizer will most likely produce similar code for both

Comment: No difference. The compiler can *easily* do transformations like this. And  `sin(x)` will take the most time anyway.

Comment: @George - *almost* the same code ([demo](https://godbolt.org/g/f6zof1))

Comment: @HB - This would be off-topic on code review. Don't suggest it spuriously.

Comment: Thank you guys for your help! Did not think that the compiler is that smart!

Comment: I think Performance is part of codereview @StoryTeller
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @HB - This isn't about improving the performance of working under-performing code. A questions that simply has "performance" in it, is not an automatic fit to code review.

Comment: Okay @StoryTeller, Thank You.

Comment: @HB Basically the Code Review site tends to frown at artificial "example snippets".  They prefer complete, working examples of the code as whole. Users can ask for a general review or ask the review to focus on certain aspects, such as RAM memory use, coding style etc.

Comment: Never test `float` or `double` with equal comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have generated assembly of both cases.

**Case 1:**

```
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 48
        movsd   QWORD PTR [rbp-24], xmm0
        movsd   QWORD PTR [rbp-32], xmm1
        pxor    xmm0, xmm0
        ucomisd xmm0, QWORD PTR [rbp-32]
        jp      .L2
        pxor    xmm0, xmm0
        ucomisd xmm0, QWORD PTR [rbp-32]
        jne     .L2
        movsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR .LC1[rip]
        movsd   QWORD PTR [rbp-8], xmm0
        jmp     .L4
.L2:
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-32]
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-40], rax
        movsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR [rbp-40]
        call    sin
        divsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR [rbp-32]
        movsd   QWORD PTR [rbp-8], xmm0
.L4:
        movsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        addsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR [rbp-24]
        leave
        ret
.LC1:
        .long   0
        .long   1072693248
```

**Case 2:**

```
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 32
        movsd   QWORD PTR [rbp-8], xmm0
        movsd   QWORD PTR [rbp-16], xmm1
        pxor    xmm0, xmm0
        ucomisd xmm0, QWORD PTR [rbp-16]
        jp      .L2
        pxor    xmm0, xmm0
        ucomisd xmm0, QWORD PTR [rbp-16]
        jne     .L2
        movsd   xmm1, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        movsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR .LC1[rip]
        addsd   xmm0, xmm1
        jmp     .L4
.L2:
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-16]
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-24], rax
        movsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR [rbp-24]
        call    sin
        divsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR [rbp-16]
        addsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
.L4:
        leave
        ret
.LC1:
        .long   0
        .long   1072693248
```

There is no difference.So, there is no speed optimization between them. So, code optimization depends on compiler.

Comment: What is that `.LC1[rip]`? What will it do?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the compiler and optimization flags. In general both codes will give the same outcome.

Answer (score 1):

Only declaring variable is not only thing that occupy memory.

```
int a = 1 + 2;
int b = 3;
int c = a + b;
```

This code will take same value as bellow code

```
int c = 1 + 2 + 3;
```

Because at the end processor will take one operation at a time in single core.
Second code add two number and hold it in stack and then take third number to add in result of first two number.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: don't worry about it!

Long answer:

`sin` will take by far the most time in this function, so a couple of additional instructions, if any, will not have any noticeable effect.

Though when in doubt, [**look**](https://godbolt.org/g/f6zof1) at the generated code.

With GCC 6.3 on x86_64, the first version uses 1 more register (xmm2) but the optimizer is able to reorder instructions better.

Version 1:

```
        ucomisd xmm1, QWORD PTR .LC1[rip]
        movapd  xmm2, xmm0
        jp      .L5
        movsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR .LC0[rip]
        je      .L7
.L5:
        movapd  xmm0, xmm1
        sub     rsp, 24
        movsd   QWORD PTR [rsp+8], xmm2
        movsd   QWORD PTR [rsp], xmm1
        call    sin
        movsd   xmm1, QWORD PTR [rsp]
        movsd   xmm2, QWORD PTR [rsp+8]
        add     rsp, 24
        divsd   xmm0, xmm1
        addsd   xmm0, xmm2
        ret
.L7:
        addsd   xmm0, xmm2
        ret
```

Version 2:

```
        ucomisd xmm1, QWORD PTR .LC0[rip]
        jp      .L2
        je      .L10
.L2:
        sub     rsp, 24
        movsd   QWORD PTR [rsp], xmm0
        movapd  xmm0, xmm1
        movsd   QWORD PTR [rsp+8], xmm1
        call    sin
        movsd   xmm1, QWORD PTR [rsp+8]
        divsd   xmm0, xmm1
        addsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR [rsp]
        add     rsp, 24
        ret
.L10:
        addsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR .LC1[rip]
        ret
```

So how much is the difference in performance between these two versions? Only a performance test can tell for sure (but my guess is you won't see any difference).